# How to put a semicolon separator in a textbox in textchange event?

Tags: vb.net

hi guys another question from a noob i manage to separate the number type in a textbox with a semicolon but the problem is when using backspace the semicolon cannot be deleted..

my code is this

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As   System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    If TextBox1.TextLength Mod 3 = 2 Then
        SendKeys.SendWait(":")

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slight fudge, and maybe a more elegant solution but...

```
Dim ValidKey As Boolean = True

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar) Then

        ValidKey = True

    Else

        ValidKey = False

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    If ValidKey And TextBox1.TextLength Mod 3 = 2 Then
            SendKeys.SendWait(":")

    End If
End Sub
```

You could of course expand on this by vetting keys for only digits if you wanted....

**EDIT**: You can minimise this code to;

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(e.KeyChar) And TextBox1.TextLength Mod 3 = 2 Then
        SendKeys.SendWait(":")

    End If

End Sub
```

Removing the TextChanged Sub, the superfluous variable and else statement...

**Edit 2**: For restricting to numerical input only...

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress

    If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) And TextBox1.TextLength Mod 3 = 2 Then

        SendKeys.SendWait(":")

    ElseIf Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) Then

        e.Handled = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: let me try that keypress event..ahmm i already have a keypress event that restrict user from entering letters so it will only accept number =)

Comment: Excellent DaniloJR! Glad I could help!

Comment: i see so you can also do that in keypress event excellent job PGallagher.. wait how do you restrict your letter? im using

Comment: If Not Isnumber(e.KeyChar) Then
        e.KeyChar = ""
    End If

Comment: but it seems that i cant apply the backspace if i use that block of code =(

Comment: once again thank you all for helping me..@PGallagher thanks man your the best it really help me =)

Comment: Hahaha... NO problems at all! Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim backPressed As Boolean = False

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If backPressed Then
        backPressed = False
        Return
    End If

    If TextBox1.TextLength Mod 3 = 2 Then
        SendKeys.SendWait(":")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = ChrW(8) Then
        backPressed = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: this one is also working so ill mark a check in this answer =)